# unfold your love

Tags: synonyms

The song, "[While My Guitar Gently Weeps](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/beatles/whilemyguitargentlyweeps.html)" by the Beatles, has these lyrics:

> I don't know why nobody told you
>
> How to **unfold** your love
>
> I don't know how someone controlled you
>
> They bought and sold you

In context, is the use of the verb "unfold" natural and idiomatic English?

If not, what other verb can substitute "unfold" to make it sound more natural, especially if the line is to be used in plain English (not in song lyrics or poems)?

Comment: I think it's mostly part of a quadruple rhyme.

Answer (score 1):

The word **reveal** could act as a partial replacement for **unfold**. Possibly **open** as well.

I believe it is "yes and no" for being *natural and idiomatic* English. Yes, in the sense that the mind image is one of revealing things not seen only on the outside. No, in that we don't normally apply **unfold** to non-physical things such as mind images. It is done, however, such as in "unfolding mystery".

Comment: Before choosing the right word to substitute "unfold", I think we need to figure out what "unfold" means in the context  of the song. What does it mean "to reveal your love"? Do you think that the songwriter was talking about a situation where somehow the listener was hiding his or her love? Because I don't think that's what he meant to say.

Comment: @JK2 Nor do I. I believe I summarized my interpretation in "*revealing things not seen only on the outside*". Beyond that the only answer might lie in each listener's knowledge, experience, and mood.

Answer (score 1):

Unfold is poetic, and this lovely song has other forced rhymes which work within the song but not for everyday conversation.

As the song starts with "the love there that's sleeping" and ends with "No one alerted you," we see that the boy wants to awaken 'her' to the love that is dormant or unexpressed. Hence, to [*unfold*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unfold)  her love and perhaps other things:

> To reveal gradually by written or spoken explanation; make known: "He unfolded his tale of woe."

Comment: Also in [Desiderata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desiderata) (also a poem): "... no doubt the universe is unfolding as it should."